# Unknown dataset URI pattern fro Sqoop2 Job

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, sqoop2

When I attempt to create a MSubmission fro a sqoop2 job. I get an error stating the URI is invalid. My CDH version is 5.4.3 and I am attempting to run this program from eclipse.

```
MSubmission submission = client.startJob(jobid);
```

I use the following for a kite URI

```
dataset:hdfs:/import
```

and I recieve the following error.

```
0    [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: CLIENT_0001:Server has returned exception
at org.apache.sqoop.client.request.ResourceRequest.doHttpRequest(ResourceRequest.java:129)
at org.apache.sqoop.client.request.ResourceRequest.put(ResourceRequest.java:179)
at org.apache.sqoop.client.request.JobResourceRequest.start(JobResourceRequest.java:112)
at org.apache.sqoop.client.request.SqoopResourceRequests.startJob(SqoopResourceRequests.java:154)
at org.apache.sqoop.client.SqoopClient.startJob(SqoopClient.java:460)
at hadoop.services.sqoop_job.main(sqoop_job.java:16)
Caused by: org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Unknown dataset URI pattern: dataset:hdfs:/import
Known patterns for hdfs:
  dataset:hdfs:/*path/:namespace/:dataset?absolute=true
  dataset:hdfs:*path/:namespace/:dataset
at org.kitesdk.data.spi.Registration.lookupDatasetUri(Registration.java:128)
at org.kitesdk.data.Datasets.exists(Datasets.java:624)
at org.kitesdk.data.Datasets.exists(Datasets.java:646)
at org.apache.sqoop.connector.kite.KiteToInitializer.initialize(KiteToInitializer.java:51)
at org.apache.sqoop.connector.kite.KiteToInitializer.initialize(KiteToInitializer.java:41)
at org.apache.sqoop.driver.JobManager.initializeConnector(JobManager.java:449)
at org.apache.sqoop.driver.JobManager.createJobRequest(JobManager.java:373)
at org.apache.sqoop.driver.JobManager.start(JobManager.java:276)
at org.apache.sqoop.handler.JobRequestHandler.startJob(JobRequestHandler.java:379)
at org.apache.sqoop.handler.JobRequestHandler.handleEvent(JobRequestHandler.java:115)
at org.apache.sqoop.server.v1.JobServlet.handlePutRequest(JobServlet.java:96)
at org.apache.sqoop.server.SqoopProtocolServlet.doPut(SqoopProtocolServlet.java:79)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:592)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:277)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:555)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've been wrestling with different APIs and configurations all day any help would be greatly appreciated.